# Seaborn jointplot kde not functionning on Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, jointplot

I am trying to use a seaborn `jointplot` with `kind="kde"`, but it doesn't work. I am on Jupyter with Python 3. Seaborn is version 0.11.1.

Here is my code :

```
sns.jointplot(data=test_df, x = "skew", y = "vol", hue="periode", kind="kde")
```

Here is the error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-204-ca814b4a75a6> in <module>
>     15 
>     16 
>---> 17 sns.jointplot(data=test_df, x = "skew", y = "vol", hue="periode", kind="kde")
>     18 
>     19 
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in jointplot(x, y, data, kind, stat_func, color, >height, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim, joint_kws, marginal_kws, annot_kws, **kwargs)>

>NameError: name 'kdeplot' is not defined
```

I don't understand the problem, as my code seems to match the example on the `Seaborn` website and I have the latest version of `Seaborn`.

Comment: using print(sns.__version__) to get the version gives me : 0.11.1 so it does not seems to be the pb.

Comment: Somehow there seems to be a problem with your seaborn installation. Maybe you could try to install it again? (Maybe some old version is getting mixed up with the current one?)